# Android style parent chaining unexpected result

Tags: android, styles

Regarding [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles), I tried to use **style chain parenting** but the behavior isn't what I expect. I've written my styles below

```
<style name="headline">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fontsize_headline</item>
</style>
<style name="white_text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/poinila_post_background</item>
</style>
<style name="west_side">
    <item name="android:background">@color/west_side</item>
</style>
<style name="west_side.headline"></style>
<style name="west_side.headline.white_text">
```

**What I expect** is a yellowish button with white text and headline text size but textColor and textSize are unchanged.

**My question is**: am I doing the right thing and the thing right? What's the reason for misbehavior?

Comment: where is the parent=""?

Comment: @isma3l If you look at the link I provided, android developer example hasn't used the parent attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple parents are not allowed in styles.

What you've done here

```
<style name="west_side.headline.white_text"/>
```

was creating a new style called white_text with the parent west_side.headline .

To get your expected result you have to add the textcolor attribute to the new style.

```
<style name="west_side.headline.white_text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/poinila_post_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: as developer.android say: 
<style name="CodeFont.Red.Big">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
 </style>

This inherits from both CodeFont and CodeFont.Red styles, then adds the android:textSize property.

Comment: Yes but have a closer look. Red's parent is CodeFont. 
Here he want to inherit from 2 different parents.

Comment: So you're telling me there's no way to combine multiple styles in android?

Comment: You can chain the styles but you can not inherit from 2 different parent styles.

Comment: Oh I got that! Thank you for your fast answer.